# Некорректно работает select на телефоне

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть `select`, который отображается с компа вот так(даже если включить мобильный режим): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в телефоне уже вот так(т.е. не отображается `:before` и т.д.):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ничего не работает( Просто нажимается на какой-то цвет и все. Нужно сделать так чтобы например при нажатии на `Цвет` сразу разворачивался мобильный `select`, а не обычный. Может я какой-то мобильный класс забыл прописать?
P.S(Да это `select` стилизованный под `dropdown`)

Comment: А почему именно select? ul li можно использовать с тем же успехом.

Comment: @alexoander, просто переделываю чужое решение, а там обязательным условием было использование `select`, сейчас уже не хочу все по новой переделывать, тем более осталась только мобильная версия

Comment: Это не совсем решение - но можно попробовать с помощью mediaquery "заставить" select выглядеть иначе на мобильных. Например через вот такое правило css @media only screen and (max-width: 480px). Ну и собственно указать те же стили, что и для обычной версии + ресайз (например выстроеные селекта не в полную ширину экрана).

Comment: @alexoander, можете рассказать по подробнее? Или хотя бы ссылку дать, на какой-нибудь источник

Comment: Ну как "указать" таргетное устройство https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/. Но а про media query можно найти в гугле- благо есть куча примеров. Но я повторюсь - я не уверен, что это может помочь т.к. некоторые мобильные браузеры могут плевать на все ваши правила